# Redirection inside subshell persists after subshell closed

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

Without and with the dry run, the script below executes as expected for A and B, respectively. The problem arises with the dry run for A: the output is inhibited, as if `1>/dev/null` persisted after the dry run. Could someone explain and resolve the problem?

```
function baz() {
    local file="$1"; shift

    # dry run
    local err=$(source "$file" "$@" 2>&1 1>/dev/null)
    [[ -z $err ]] || { echo "Exiting"; return 1; }

    # live run
    local output=$(source "$file" "$@")
    [[ -z $output ]] || echo "$output"
}

baz <(cat <<EOF
echo "I was given $# argument(s):"  # A
# eecho "I was given $# argument(s):" # B
printf "%s " "$@"
EOF
) 'foo' 'bar'
```

Other:

```
$ uname  -a
6.7.3-arch1-2 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri, 02 Feb 2024 17:03:55 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.26(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: What happens if you invert the positions of the `# dry run` and the `# live run` sections of the code?

Comment: @Samveen that would defeat the purpose so please make clear what you're leading   at.

Comment: You're expecting a socket descriptor to work the same way as a file name. That isn't going to happen, as the semantics are different.

Answer (score 5):

There are two separate problems in your code:

1. You forgot quotes around `EOF` so the `$#`/`$@` will be expanded in the here document at the time that here document is parsed.
2. You're trying to read twice until the end-of-file from a named pipe (aka fifo)

For 1, compare:

```
$ bash --norc -s {1..42}
bash-5.3$ cat << EOF
> echo "$#"
> EOF
echo "42"
bash-5.3$ cat << 'EOF'
> echo "$#"
> EOF
echo "$#"
```

Quoting the delimiter for the heredoc (here with `'EOF'` but you could also quote only some part of it like in `\EOF` same as `'E'OF` to the same effect) causes expansions inside not to be performed.

For 2, a simpler reproducer would be:

```
myfunction() {
  local file="$1"
  stat -Lc '$file (%n) is a %F.' -- "$file"
  echo First round:
  cat -- "$file"
  echo Second round:
  cat -- "$file"
  echo Done.
}
myfunction <(echo some text)
```

(here assuming a GNU or GNU-like implementation of `stat`).

Which gives:

```
bash-5.3$ myfunction <(echo some text)
$file (/dev/fd/63) is a fifo.
First round:
some text
Second round:
Done.
```

`<(cmd)` expands to a named pipe or something that behaves like a named pipe on systems that have `/dev/fd`. And you can only read once the contents of a pipe.

In `cmd1 <(cmd2)`, `cmd1` and `cmd2` run concurrently like in `cmd2 | cmd1`, the difference being that in `cmd2 | cmd1`, `cmd2`'s output is readily available on `cmd1`'s fd 0 while in `cmd1 <(cmd2)`, `cmd1` needs to open its first argument (the `/dev/fd/63` that `<(cmd2)` expanded to above) to get a fd where to read the output from.

In either case, once `cmd2`'s output has been read, it can't be read again.

With older versions of bash (5.0 or below), you could have gotten away with:

```
bash-5.0$ myfunction /dev/fd/3 3<< 'EOF'
> echo "$#"
> EOF
$file (/dev/fd/3) is a regular file.
First round:
echo "$#"
Second round:
echo "$#"
Done.
```

As back then, here-documents were still implemented as deleted  *regular files* as in the original Bourne shell implementation, or as they still are in other shells such as zsh. In newer versions, bash has switched to using pipes when the here-doc is small enough that pipes can be used without deadlocks:

```
bash-5.3$ myfunction /dev/fd/3 3<< 'EOF'
> echo "$#"
> EOF
$file (/dev/fd/3) is a fifo.
First round:
echo "$#"
Second round:
Done.
```

```
bash-5.3$ myfunction /dev/fd/3 3<< EOF | grep -e 9999 -e '[[:alpha:]]'
> $(seq 40000)
> EOF
$file (/dev/fd/3) is a regular file.
First round:
9999
19999
29999
39999
Second round:
9999
19999
29999
39999
Done.
```

To be able to read the file more than once, you need it to be a *regular* file, so the options are either to

- switch to `zsh` for instance and use that `/dev/fd/3 3<< 'EOF'` approach
- switch to `zsh` and use its `=(...)` form of process substitution that uses temporary files (and takes care of cleanup itself) instead of fifos (and where `cmd2` and `cmd1` run sequentially in `cmd1 =(cmd2)`):

  ```
  zsh% myfunction =(<<'EOF'
  cmdsubst¹ heredoc> echo "$#"
  cmdsubst¹ heredoc> EOF
  cmdsubst¹> )
  $file (/tmp/zsh7xSwLQ) is a regular file.
  First round:
  echo "$#"
  Second round:
  echo "$#"
  Done.
  ```
- or if you have to use bash, do the temp file handling by hand using `mktemp` for instance on systems that have one (most these days). That can be done with it deleted in advance like in original here-documents so you don't have to worry about clean-up as much:

  ```
  file=$(mktemp) || exit
  <<'EOF' cat > "$file"
  echo "$#"
  EOF
  {
    rm -f -- "$file" && myfunction /dev/fd/3
  } 3< "$file"
  ```

  Though that approach only works on Linux or Cygwin where `/dev/fd/n` are *magic symlinks* to the original files. On other systems, opening `/dev/fd/n` acts like `dup(n)` so it does not move back to the beginning of the file each time you open it.

Or in your case, you could use `eval` instead of `source` and pass the code to run in memory rather than files/fifos:

```
myfunction() {
  local code="$1"; shift
  echo First round:
  eval -- "$code"
  echo Second round:
  eval -- "$code"
}

myfunction "$(cat <<'EOF'
echo "I got $# argument${2+s}${1+: $@}"
EOF
)" more args
```

Note the `$(...)` command substitution (which needs to be quoted to prevent split+glob (split only in zsh)) instead of `<(...)`/`=(...)` process substitution.

Which gives:

```
First round:
I got 2 arguments: more args
Second round:
I got 2 arguments: more args
```

---

<sup>¹ note that [despite what that `cmdsubst` may suggest](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2024/msg00264.html), that's a *process substitution* here, not *command substitution*.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The section below creates a <strike>socket</strike> pipe stream descriptor, not a file descriptor:

```
cat <<EOF
...
EOF
```

The first time this stream is read, (in the `# dry run` section), the read pointer of the descriptor reaches the End-of-File.

The `# live run` section only sees the EOF (i.e. the End-of-File, not the `EOF` string), and so there is nothing actually run in the `# live run` section.

A solution I usually use in cases like this is to use `mktemp` as below:

```
TS="$(mktemp /tmp/subscript-XXXXXX.sh)"

cat >$TS <__EOF
...
__EOF

bash -x $TS fee fi fo fum

rm -f $TS
```

*Edit: As pointed out by the OP, the usage of `mktemp` is very flexible, and need not follow my exact example as above. The example was picked from one of my use cases, and not tailored to the OP's scenario.*

Comment: And the resolution: copying the content of the descriptor to a temporary file?

Comment: Yes. That is the resolution.

Comment: The solution you're proposing seems to be at the calling point. Here is one within the function itself: `temp=$(mktemp); cat "$file" > "$temp"`, and replace `file` by `temp` in the dry and live runs. This works as expected for A and B. OTOH `< $file > $temp` does not work, presumably for the reason  you pointed out.

Comment: @Erwann Updated to include your point about my example.

Comment: it's a pipe, not a socket, as shown in Stéphane Chazelas's answer.

Comment: Corrected `:facepalm:`

Answer (score 0):

The function expects a file, but in the example, it was passed `<(cat << EOF ...)`, in other words a here-doc inside a process substitution. [As noted about the latter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/771781/142980), "The first time this stream is read, the read pointer of the descriptor reaches the End-of-File." Accordingly, to accommodate such file objects, the resolution is to copy the content thereof, to a temporary file, and use it thereafter:

`script.sh`:

```
function baz() {
    local file="$1"; shift

    temp=$(mktemp)
    trap '{ rm -f "$temp"; }' EXIT ERR
    cat "$file" > "$temp"

    # dry run
    local err=$(source "$temp" "$@" 2>&1 1>/dev/null)
    [[ -z $err ]] || { echo "Exiting"; return 1; }

    # live run
    local output=$(source "$temp" "$@")
    [[ -z $output ]] || echo "$output"
}

baz <(cat << 'EOF'
# echo "I was given $# argument(s):"  # A
eecho "I was given $# argument(s):" # B
printf "%s " "$@"
EOF
) 'foo' 'bar'
```

Under A:

```
$ source script.sh 'foo' 'bar'
I was given 2 argument(s):
foo bar
```

Under B:

```
$ source script.sh 'foo' 'bar´
Exiting
```

Extra:

- [As noted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/771786/142980), "without quotes around [the lead] EOF the positional parameters are expanded in the here document at the time that here document is parsed." Corrected accordingly.

Comment: Not related to the problem you're having, but you should note that since you haven't escaped `$#` or `$@` in the heredoc and as the heredoc marker isn't quoted either, `$#` and `$@` are substituted in the heredoc itself (if you do `cat "$temp"` you'll see it already has `2` and `foo bar` in place of `$#` and `$@`). Passing `'foo' 'bar'` to `baz` or using `"$@` in `source ... "$@"` isn't doing anything useful given the code in the question or here.